# LXD Installation Not Working with Snapcraft

Tags: snap, lxd

I installed LXD with all the defaults, but when I get an error:

```
$ snapcraft cleanbuild
Something seems to be wrong with your installation of LXD. Refer to the documentation at https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli.
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/snap-a-website?_ga=2.231805343.1657809003.1520290287-2078285627.1520290287#4), but snapcraft still won't do a cleanbuild. How can I resolve this?

LXD Defaults:

```
Do you want to configure a new storage pool (yes/no) [default=yes]? yes
Name of the new storage pool [default=default]: 
Name of the storage backend to use (dir, btrfs, ceph, lvm, zfs) [default=zfs]: 
Create a new ZFS pool (yes/no) [default=yes]? 
Would you like to use an existing block device (yes/no) [default=no]? 
Size in GB of the new loop device (1GB minimum) [default=34GB]: 
Would you like LXD to be available over the network (yes/no) [default=no]? 
Would you like stale cached images to be updated automatically (yes/no) [default=yes]? 
Would you like to create a new network bridge (yes/no) [default=yes]? 
What should the new bridge be called [default=lxdbr0]? 
What IPv4 address should be used (CIDR subnet notation, “auto” or “none”) [default=auto]? 
What IPv6 address should be used (CIDR subnet notation, “auto” or “none”) [default=auto]? 
LXD has been successfully configured.
```

Comment: Did you read `https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli`, and see how it compares with your default configuration?

Comment: I didn't see how what it said applied to the problem I had. The only command I typed in that the documentation had too was "sudo lxd init", and it didn't go into detail with the default settings.